# for loop skipping getline

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, struct

Hello everyone I am doing a programming assignment on structured data and I believe I understand how structs work.

I am trying to read in a list of student names, ID numbers (A-Numbers), and their balances.

When I compile my code though, it will read everything in the first time around, but the second time around the loop and every time after, it prompts for the username but skips the getline and goes straight to A-Number and A-number entry.

Any help would be appreciated. Just trying to figure out how to make the getline work every time the loop goes around.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    const int maxStudents = 30;
    struct Students{
        string studentName;
        int aNumber;
        double outstandingBalance;};

    Students students[maxStudents];

    for(int count = 0; count < maxStudents-1; count++)
    {
        cout<<"Student Name:";
                cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,students[count].studentName);
        cout<<"\nA-Number:";
        cin>>students[count].aNumber;
        if(students[count].aNumber == -999)
            break;
        cout<<"\nOutstanding Balance:";
        cin>>students[count].outstandingBalance;
    }

    cout<<setw(20)<<"A-Number"<<"Name"<<"Balance";

    for(int count2 = 29; count2 >= maxStudents-1; count2--)
        cout<<setw(20)<<students[count2].aNumber<<students[count2].studentName<<students[count2].outstandingBalance;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can't you just use `cin>>students[count].studentName;`. It works btw

Comment: @Neox - not if the student's name has a space in it, like 'John Hancock' does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason what you're doing doesn't work is that the '>>' operators the
first time through don't extract the trailing `'\n'`, the next `getline`
sees it, and returns immediately with an empty line.

The simple answer is: don't mix `getline` and `>>`.  If the input is
line oriented, use `getline`.  If you need to parse data in the line
using `>>`, use the string read by `getline` to initialize a
`std::istringstream`, and use `>>` on it.

Comment: I understand what I did wrong but the rest of your answer has left me completely confused as to what youre trying to tell me to do.

Comment: I used a cin.ignore(); before getline to fix my problem.

Comment: @sircrisp: Create an `std::istringstream` from the `std::string` that contains the line read. You can then exctract space-seperated items from the stream the same way you do with `std::cin`: `istr >> item;`

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip. Can't use it for this particular program though because of the requirements for homework. Has to be a string.

Comment: What has to be a string?  Mixing `getline` and `>>` is **not** a good technique.  It is extremely fragile, and will cause all sorts of problems with unexpected input.  The only viable solution is to use `getline` after each prompt; when you need an `int` or a `double`, put the line (which should have type `std::string`) into a `std::istringstream`, and use `>>` on that.

Comment: with regards to the `ignore`: it's not as robust as just using `getline`, but if you do go that route, the `ignore` should follow the `>>`, not precede the `getline`.  The idea is to ensure that after every input, the last character extracted is tne `'\n'`.

Comment: Also: check the state of the stream after every input.  Your code will behave very funny if someone inputs `"abc"` when they should input a number.  (This is, in fact, a major benefit of the `getline`/`istringstream` approach.  The error in such cases will be on the `istringstream`, which is local to the loop.  And regardless of what happens, the main input remains synchronized on the lines.)

Answer (score 4):

Look up [C++ FAQ on iostreams](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/input-output.html).

Item 15.6 specifically deals with your problem ("Why is my program ignoring my input request after the first iteration?"), but you may find the whole page useful.

HTH,

Answer (score 4):

Put

`cin.ignore();`

at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with mixing `cin` and `getline`. Formatted input (with the >> operator) and unformatted input (getline is an example) don't play well together. You should definitely read more about it. [Click here for more  explanation](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/365028/array-of-strings-input-problem).

Here is the solution to your problem.
`cin.ignore(1024, '\n');` is the key.

```
for(int count = 0; count < maxStudents-1; count++)
{
    ...
    cout<<"\nOutstanding Balance:";
    cin>>students[count].outstandingBalance;
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with the skipping with getline()

Use it like this std::getline(cin>>ws,a);

Using ws will skip the white space.